# Spring Security OAuth2 - Is it Possible to Change Table and Column Names?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I am working on building an OAuth2 enabled application using Spring Boot and Spring Security. Initially, I used the schema noted [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql). With that, I was able to get the application at least functioning. However, I would like to have the database objects named a little differently - specifically using PascalCase rather than underscores.

For example, instead of

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[oauth_client_details](
    [client_id] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [resource_ids] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [client_secret] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [scope] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [authorized_grant_types] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [web_server_redirect_uri] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [authorities] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [access_token_validity] [int] NULL,
    [refresh_token_validity] [int] NULL,
    [additional_information] [varchar](4096) NULL,
    [autoapprove] [varchar](256) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [client_id] ASC
)
```

I would like to have:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OAuthClientDetails](
    [ClientID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ResourceIDs] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [ClientSecret] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Scope] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [AuthorizedGrantTypes] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [AccessTokenValidity] [int] NULL,
    [RefreshTokenValidity] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OAuthClientDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientID] ASC
)
```

I am not positive how (or if it is possible) to override these expectations. For example, when I attempted to use the PascalCase database, it is still expecting the original naming style. I receive the following when requesting a token:

```
"message": "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select client_id, client_secret, resource_ids, scope, authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri, authorities, access_token_validity, refresh_token_validity, additional_information, autoapprove from oauth_client_details where client_id = ?]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'oauth_client_details'.",
"path": "/oauth/token"
```

My AuthServerConfig:

```
 @EnableAuthorizationServer


 @Configuration
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private AccessTokenConverter converter;

 private final AppConfig appConfig; 

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
public AuthServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AppConfig appConfig) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {


    configurer.jdbc(appConfig.dataSource());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(converter)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}



   @Bean
   @Primary //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
   public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
      DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
      defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
      defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
      return defaultTokenServices;
   }
```

My AppConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {


    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }    

    // Reference: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

    /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
    ** TODO 
    * Secure key file for deployment.
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
       @Bean
       public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
          JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
          KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = 
                  new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("mytest.jks"), "mypass".toCharArray());
                converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("mytest"));
          return converter;
       }


       @Bean
       public TokenStore tokenStore() {
          return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
       }
```

According to the [Spring Security OAuth Documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

```
NOTE: the schema for the JDBC service is not packaged with the library (because there are too many variations you might like to use in practice), but there is an example you can start from in the test code in github.
```

However, it does seem to make some assumptions about the structure. For example, I never explicitly "told" the application to use a table called `o_auth_client_details`.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can customize the `JdbcClientDetailsService`, see

- [`setDeleteClientDetailsSql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html#setDeleteClientDetailsSql(java.lang.String))
- [`setFindClientDetailsSql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html#setFindClientDetailsSql(java.lang.String))
- [`setInsertClientDetailsSql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html#setInsertClientDetailsSql(java.lang.String))
- [`setSelectClientDetailsSql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html#setSelectClientDetailsSql(java.lang.String))
- [`setUpdateClientDetailsSql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html#setUpdateClientDetailsSql(java.lang.String))
- [`setUpdateClientSecretSql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html#setUpdateClientSecretSql(java.lang.String))

and add it to your configurer, see [`ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer#withClientDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/configurers/ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer.html#withClientDetails(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService)):

> **withClientDetails**
>
> ```java
> public ClientDetailsServiceBuilder<?> withClientDetails(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) throws Exception
> ```

Your modified code:

```java
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

     JdbcClientDetailsService clientDetailsService= new JdbcClientDetailsService(appConfig.dataSource()); 
     clientDetailsService.setDeleteClientDetailsSql(myDeleteClientDetailsSql);
     clientDetailsService.setFindClientDetailsSql(myFindClientDetailsSql); 
     clientDetailsService.setInsertClientDetailsSql(myInsertClientDetailsSql); 
     clientDetailsService.setInsertClientDetailsSql(myInsertClientDetailsSql); 
     clientDetailsService.setSelectClientDetailsSql(mySelectClientDetailsSql); 
     clientDetailsService.setUpdateClientDetailsSql(myUpdateClientDetailsSql); 
     clientDetailsService.setUpdateClientSecretSql(myUpdateClientSecretSql); 

     configurer.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's so simple.
Follow these steps:

1. find **JdbcClientDetailsService** and **JdbcTokenStore** from oauth2 jar file or user  on this classes in **spring-security.xml** config file.

```xml
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStor*">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

2. make a copy of each class and create new one in your program. then change name of tables and columns to your appropriate names (I change table and column names).

```java
public class CustomeJdbcTokenStore implements TokenStore { 
    private String insertAccessTokenSql = "insert oauthAccessToken
        (tokenId, token, authenticationId, username, clientId, authentication, refreshToken) 
        values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private String selectAccessTokenSql = "select tokenId, token from 
         oauthAccessToken where tokenId = ?";

    private String selectAccessTokenAuthenticationSql = "select tokenId, authentication from 
         oauthAccessToken where tokenId = ?";
```

3. Add new class to **spring-security.xml** file.

```xml
<bean id="tokenStore" class="ir.hossein.irtms.service.CustomJdbcTokenStore**">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```